# CoreData fetch from privateContext nil while record exists on MainContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've two CoreData contexts: one private for background processes and the MainContext associated with the UI thread. They are independent each other and are directly backed by the same `NSPersistenceStoreCoordinator`. If I perform a certain fetch from the MainContext my record returns an object, if I do the same on the privateContext I get nil.

Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Thank you

UPDATE (to answer to The Dreams Wind)

A piece of code to see how I manage the data:

```
let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
                    privateContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
                    privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
privateContext.perform {
 //I create some records like this
var myObj = MyObject(context: privateContext)
//assign properties
privateContext.save()
}
```

The `save()` triggers my CoreData `didSave` callback in the `AppDelegate` where I merge the two context to keep the main context updated

```
let senderMoc = notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext
if senderMOC != mainContext{
    mainContext.perform {
        mainContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
    }
}
```

I expected that the mainContext could be behind the private one due to pending objects not saved yet, not the contrary.

The private context is instantiated inside a method, so I think it doesn't retain any object. Is it right? The main context, on the contrary lives as long as the app is running, so this should retain all objects it already have loaded in memory from `NSPersistenceStoreCoordinator` right?

Comment: Could you please include some piece of code where we can see how you retain data from the contexts?

Comment: Why are you using peer to peer managed object context architecture, this used to be the approach in legacy system (prior to iOS 5) from iOS 5 onwards apple suggests establishing parent child architecture between private and main managed object context, peer to peer is cumbersome as keeping them in sync with each others changes is a manual task (unlike parent child structure where changes in child context automatically propagates to parent) also in case of peer to peer structure you need to resolve the conflicts manually

Comment: I tried the parent/child relationship, but I face the same problem. So I tried even this legacy way. When I figure out the real problem I'll try to return to parent/child context. Do you think that my problem is due to conflicts? I'm sure I don't update the same object in the main context.